# VPN deleting routes from another

Tags: networking, vpn, mac-osx

When I connect to first VPN (`utun4`) and I run the command `ip route`, this is the output I get:

```
10.10.0.0/16 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
10.100.0.0/16 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
10.250.152.0/21 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
172.27.224.0/20 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
172.27.232.0/21 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
172.27.232.1/32 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
```

But when I connect to the second one (`utun3`), it deletes all `10.x.x.x` entries for `utun4`:

```
default via link#19 dev utun3
9.49.252.128/27 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
9.57.162.0/24 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
9.187.76.0/27 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
9.187.76.128/25 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
10.38.0.101/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
10.38.96.0/20 dev utun3  scope link
10.64.0.111/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
10.250.152.2/32 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
18.214.230.18/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
34.231.46.80/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
50.17.199.7/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
52.202.191.19/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
52.206.134.40/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
54.197.131.158/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
64.26.251.136/30 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
64.26.251.192/26 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
64.26.255.0/25 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
72.163.1.80/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
100.64.0.0/11 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
144.188.129.17/32 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
172.22.0.0/16 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
172.23.0.0/16 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
172.24.0.0/16 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3
172.27.224.0/20 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
172.27.232.0/21 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
172.27.232.1/32 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
224.0.0.0/4 dev utun3  scope link
255.255.255.255/32 dev utun3  scope link
```

Output for `ip r | grep utun4`:

```
10.250.152.2/32 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
172.27.224.0/20 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
172.27.232.0/21 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
172.27.232.1/32 via 172.27.232.29 dev utun4
```

Only `10.250.152.2/32` remains, and I believe it's because it's as specific as it could. Why does it happen? How can I prioritize `utun4`? I am using MacOS.

Comment: Which VPN software is this? NB: this is precise reason why the routes installed by the VPN should be as narrow as possible.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov OpenVPN and AnyConnect, AnyConnect is the one creating utun3

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% on this, but I see your second VPN has the network/route:
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.38.110.180 dev utun3

That's a bit wonky because it covers the same range as these on utun4:
10.10.0.0/16 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
10.100.0.0/16 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4
10.250.152.0/21 via 172.27.232.1 dev utun4

I don't know how your VPN software handles it but it may just be removing routes/subnets that were previously defined if the new routes overlap.

Try to be more specific instead of using the 10.0.0.0/8.  Just to test, you could remove just that one route to see if it helps or not.

You could also try adding [metrics](https://superuser.com/questions/1167244/interpreting-the-metric-column-in-routing-table) to your routes to tell your client which route to prefer.

One last idea - some VPNs are very strict on the routes they allow their clients to have.  I'd check for that too.

Comment: I am starting to believe it's about one of the VPNs behavior. It's a MacOS so no metrics on the routes, it just prioritizes devices. I am thinking about building something to deal with overlapping VPNs...

Comment: @Horus I see from the other comment that you are using AnyConnect.  From my experience AnyConnect really really wants to be in charge of your routes when it's active - usually for good security reasons.